# Sudden FPS drop in Rainbow Six Siege

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

While trying to get in a match my FPS suddenly drops. Do you know the reason? My graphics are set to custom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even your graphics are in custom they might be ultra I would check that first If that doesnt work what I did was reinstalling r6 siege and uplay

These worked fine for me

Comment: You were right my graphics were set to custom After I took them to low I started having 60 FPS without any sudden drops

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to pinpoint a reason without all the parameters (Windows, build, PC specs).

It can be related with the latest Win update which affected a lot of games.

You can try to right click your Rainbow Six Siege .exe file (Steam->Steamapps-> Common->Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege), go to properties, hit "*compatibility*" and then click on "**disable fullscreen optimization**"

This was a solution for the latest Win patches.

Comment: I don't think so It didn't work Thank you anyway